# Pnp Rich Text Editor resizes automatically. How did I stop it from doing this?

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, pnp, react, rich-text

I am using the pnp rich text editor. The textbox resizes itself automatically to accommodate the amount of characters in the text box. If there are too many characters, the textbox grows in size. How do I stop this so that the textbox will scroll down instead of growing in size as more characters are entered.

I attached a gif that shows the problem.

[image: RichTextResize]

```
<div className={`${styles.customInputBody}`}>
              <RichText id= {`richTextBody`} styleOptions={{showStyles:true, showBold:true, showUnderline:true, showItalic:true, showMore:true}} label="Add a message" value={this.props.richTextValue}
                onChange={(text)=>this.onTextChange(text)}
              />
              </div>
```